# How can I show auto_now_add field in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model (as below) and in that, I've set [**`auto_now_add=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the `DateTimeField`

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

From the doc,

> As currently implemented, setting `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` to `True` will cause the field to have `editable=False` and `blank=True` set.

Q: How Can I show this **`auto_now_add`** field in Django Admin? (by default Django Admin doesn't show `auto_now_add` fields)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can *forcefully* show the `auto_now_add=True` fields by adding the particular field(s) to the [**`readonly_fields`** - (Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) list

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('timestamp',)


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: Goes in admin.py